# Проблема с функциями

Tags: javascript, jquery

В ссылках у меня назначен запуск функции `onClick="getTaskStatus(передаю переменные);return false;`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getTaskStatus=function(переменные){
        $("#filters-successfully").bind("click", function(){
            console.log('a');
        });

        $("#filters-not-successfully").bind("click", function(){
            console.log('b');
        });
        $.ajax ({
          ...
        });
    }
});
```

Если один раз нажать на ссылку и начать выбирать `input`'ы, то в консоль будет выводиться "a" или "b". Если нажать на вторую ссылку, то будет выводиться уже по два "a" или "b". Если нажать на третью ссылку, то будет выводиться уже по 3 буквы, и так далее. Вот я и не пойму, в чем особенность.

Comment: Пожалуйста, оставляя вопрос прилагайте к нему **минимально воспроизводимый пример кода**. Как отвечающие должны понять, где у вас проблема, если вы привели скрипт без использующего его HTML-кода? Кроме того, следует указывать **ожидаемое поведение** вашего кода. Как вы предлагаете определить ошибку людям, которым не привели пример нормальной работы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `.bind` подписывает на событие, в твоем случае элемент `#filters-not-successfully`, каждый раз когда вызывается метод `getTaskStatus`. Это не правильно. Ты можешь вынести подпись на событие за метод `getTaskStatus` и вызывать в ручную внутри метода событие `.click`.

Примерно так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#filters-successfully").bind("click", function(){
       console.log('a');
    });

    $("#filters-not-successfully").bind("click", function(){
       console.log('b');
    });
    getTaskStatus=function(переменные){
        $.ajax ({
          ...
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Так вот проблема у меня, у меня при выборе input, нужно вызвать функцию, и передать туда параметры, которые передаются в функцию getTaskStatus.. Вот мб можно как-то и по другому сделать, но пока не придумал как

Comment: html код покажи, я не вижу структуру страницы, измени свой вопрос

Comment: Да пока решил проблему, добавив в начало функции  unbind();

Comment: ну можно конечно постоянно делать unbind, это конечно рабочий подход, но не правильный